# Silently sending an email from a Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-7, xna

Is it possible to silently send an email from a Windows Phone 7 device?

The reason I ask is because I would like to have a system from which an app will send information to a server which the server will log. I figure if I use emails it would be a lot more straightforward than some other system.

As you can probably guess from my question I'm in completely unexplored territory here.

Comment: Instead of sending emails have you considered using a Web Service?

Comment: Oh right, I'll look into web services then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to send emails, so long as you are running the SMTP server on your server.

Web services are designed for this sort of thing, email isn't.  You won't find emails simpler.  Look into WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, sending email can be achieved with the *EmailComposeTask*.
To use the EmailComposeTask , you must include the namespace Microsoft.Phone.Tasks .

```
*`Using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks ;`*
```

This namespace can be found in the Microsoft.Phone.dll
To send the email , create an instance of the EmailComposeTask and set the appropriate properties like
To , Subject and Body of the Email .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
    emailcomposer.To = "<a href="mailto:test@ginktage.com">test@ginktage.com</a>";
    emailcomposer.Subject = "subject from test app";
    emailcomposer.Body = "This is a test mail from Email Composer";
    emailcomposer.Show();
}
```

When the Show method is called , the EmailComposer is opened which lets the user to click the send button to send the email

I hope it's clear :)

Comment: That's not "silently" though.

Comment: Not silent email sending functionality.

Comment: Email needs to be sent in the background without the Show() method being used.